# How to cast a Ray using local pivot of an object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I cast a Ray from the position of the object toward the other way of the X local pivot arrow like i show with the green arrow in the screenshot? I want to use the local pivot point because if i rotate the Tile i want the Ray to rotate too.

[image]

```
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, /* ? */, out hit, maxRayDis)) {

}
```

I tried this but it's doesn't seem to work.

```
Vector3 testVec = new Vector3 (transform.localPosition.x, 0, 0);

Debug.DrawLine (transform.position, testVec, Color.green);
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, testVec, out hit, maxRayDis)) {

}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set:

```
testVec = -transform.right;
```

Comment: It doesn't cast any Ray using this either.

Comment: Use DrawRay() to view it `Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, testVec*maxRayDis, Color.green);`

Answer (score 0):

You missed translating you local vector to world space. Your code should be modified like this:

```
Vector3 testVec = transform.TransformVector(new Vector3 (transform.localPosition.x, 0, 0));

Debug.DrawLine (transform.position, testVec, Color.green);
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, testVec, out hit, maxRayDis)) {

}
```

Comment: I get this result with this code http://image.prntscr.com/image/b91f8e4abda8428bbd66bf74c202759d.png

Comment: try this: 
       Vector3 testVec = transform.forward;

        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + testVec, Color.green);

Comment: for short: 
       Vector3 testVec = transform.position + transform.forward;